# Erlang Case of a Gamma Distribution

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

For part a) I get $ E(X)=\alpha\beta=\frac{n}{\lambda}. $ Thus the answer is $\frac{10}{0.5}=20$ minutes. I am not sure how to do b). Any help?

The special case of the gamma distribution in
which $\alpha$ is a positive integer $n$ is called an Erlang
distribution. If we replace $\beta$ by $1/\lambda$ in Expression
(4.7), the Erlang pdf is 
$ f(x;\lambda,n)=\frac{\lambda(\lambda{x})^{n-1}e^{-\lambda{x}}}{(n-1!)} $ for $ x\geq0$ and $ 0 $ otherwise.

It can be shown that if the times between successive
events are independent, each with an exponential
distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then the
total time $X$ that elapses before all of the next $n$
events occur has pdf $f(x; l, n)$.

a. What is the expected value of $X$? If the time (in
minutes) between arrivals of successive customers
is exponentially distributed with $\lambda = .5$,
how much time can be expected to elapse
before the tenth customer arrives?

b. If customer interarrival time is exponentially
distributed with $\lambda = .5$, what is the probability
that the tenth customer (after the one who has
just arrived) will arrive within the next
30 min?

c. The event ${X \leq t}$ occurs if and only if at least $n$
events occur in the next t units of time. Use the
fact that the number of events occurring in an
interval of length $t$ has a Poisson distribution
with parameter $\lambda{t}$ to write an expression (involving
Poisson probabilities) for the Erlang
cumulative distribution function $F(t;\lambda,n)=O(X\leq t) $.

Comment: (b) does not seem to have a simple closed form.  So what methods do you allow? For example in R you might use something like `pgamma(30, shape=10, rate=0.5)`

Comment: Sorry, where should I input those numbers? I tried integrating to get a cdf but it seemed to complicated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, didn't seem to read your question right, I am not sure what methods can be used to solve this problem, for example I am not sure if finding a cdf will work or if I should find std. deviation and try to use that.